# Use of didSet property observer in custom UITableCell to update TextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didset

I have a table that displays a list of pupils and their chosen subjects. The pupil's name are displayed as table section headers and each chosen subject is displayed as table rows for each section. I have a simple class to store the pupil's name as a string and their subjects as an array as follows:

```
import UIKit

class TableText: NSObject {

var name: String

var subject: [String]

init(name: String, subject: [String]) {
    self.name = name
    self.subject = subject

 }

}
```

In my custom TableViewCell I have a didSet property observer to track any changes to each pupil's chosen subjects (i.e. I have a textView that the user can click on and modify or change a subject. My didSet is currently as follows:

```
var tableText: TableText? {

    didSet {

        let mySubject = myTextView.text
        if ((tableText?.subject.contains(mySubject)) != nil) {          
        }          
    }
}
```

My cellForRowAtIndexPath in my TableViewController is as follows:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myTableViewCell

   cell.delegate = self

    let pupil = tableTexts[indexPath.section]

    cell.myTextView.text = pupil.subject[indexPath.row]

    cell.subject = pupil.subject[indexPath.row]
    cell.name = pupil.name
    print("name: \(cell.name) subject: \(cell.subject)")

    return cell
}
```

I'm puzzled at how to take the data from the tableView of each pupil and pupil's subjects and use didSet to set the pupil's name and list of subjects so I can monitor the textViews and update changes to the model as required. I much appreciate any assistance.

Comment: it's not entirely clear to me what kind of changes you mean and if those changes come from the model or from the UI. also, is there any code you tried so far?

Comment: It seems to me you want to propagate the changes in the textField to your model. Is this right?